# T-test in R for the below

Tags: r

I want to run a t.test on R. Between average length of stay and peer group(large and Medium hospital)

```
alos1 <- alos %>% filter(`Peer group` == "Large hospitals")
alos2 <- alos %>% filter(`Peer group` == "Medium hospitals")
Large_Medium <- alos1 %>% full_join(alos2)
Clean <- Large_Medium %>% filter(!`Average length of stay (days)`== "NP")
t.test(
  peer_group ~ Average_length_of_stay
  data = Clean
  var.equal = TRUE
  alternative = "two-sided"
)
```

The above code is what i used to sort the data and then t.test however i keep getting an error.

Using Dput as ronak suggested heres my data.

```
   structure(list(`Reporting unit` = c("Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]"), `Reporting unit type` = c("Hospital", 
"Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", 
"Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital"), State = c("NSW", "NSW", 
"NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW"), `Local Hospital Network (LHN)` = c("Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health"
), `Peer group` = c("Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", 
"Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", 
"Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals"), `Time period` = c("2011–12", 
"2012–13", "2013–14", "2014–15", "2015–16", "2016–17", "2011–12", 
"2012–13", "2013–14", "2014–15"), Category = c("Cellulitis", 
"Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)"
), `Total number of stays` = c(111, 116, 141, 155, 210, 196, 
109, 116, 75, 132), `Number of overnight stays` = c(92, 98, 115, 
123, 166, 155, 108, 113, 71, 122), `Percentage of overnight stays` = c(0.83, 
0.84, 0.82, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.99, 0.97, 0.95, 0.92), `Average length of stay (days)` = c(3.9, 
3.3, 3.1, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 5.8, 4.6, 5.7, 4.4), `Peer group average (days)` = c(3.7, 
3.5, 3.3, 3.2, 3, 3, 4.8, 4.4, 4.2, 3.9), `Total overnight patient bed days` = c(356, 
326, 351, 306, 431, 418, 622, 518, 405, 538)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

I get a new error after correctly naming my columns. It is as follows. new error: **Error in t.test.formula(Peer group ~ Average length of stay (days), : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels**

I would appreciate some help please

Comment: In general it would be helpful to post the specific error message. However one immediate fix is you'll need commas after each argument in `t.test`. So put a comma at the end of each line (besides the last).

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for the quick reply. ive posted it on a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584580/t-test-in-r-not-working-error-and-data-picture-included                                                  Hopefully its formatted a bit better. I added the commas but it didnt work.

Comment: @mishal2028 you should not. Improve this question instead. Add data using `dput` and not as images. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Another request, mishal2028: please do not assume that we will be willing to transcribe an image of data into something we can use. From the looks of your image, though you do not have columns named `peer_group` nor `Average_length_of_stay`, your names look like they have spaces in them.

Comment: ive tried both and with and without _ it still doesnt not work. @r2evans

Comment: sorry @RonakShah new here and this assignment has me very stressed. I apologise.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not doing anything more with an image. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Have you tried `names(Clean)` to see how R thinks the names should be referenced?

Comment: I understand but by adding images you are not helping anybody. A good question is when you share data using `dput` so that we can copy-paste into our R session and work on it. With images we can't do anything more than guess work. If the data is too big use `dput(head(df, 10))`.

Comment: Ive added the Dput. Hope you guys can help. Yup @r2evans still no luck sir

Comment: The `dput` you have shared does not have enough data points but I think you have got your column names wrong. There are no underscores in your names. Can you try `t.test(
  \`Peer group\` ~ \`Average length of stay (days)\`,
  data = Clean,
  var.equal = TRUE,
  alternative = "two-sided"
)`

Comment: I get a error as follows: Error: unexpected symbol in "t.test( Peer group". The dataset has over 6000 observations. shall i post a larger one? @RonakShah

Comment: I am afraid that you are not copy-pasting my comment correctly. You have unconventional column names so you need to use backticks to refer them.

Comment: Sorry new error: Error in t.test.formula(`Peer group` ~ `Average length of stay (days)`,  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213058/discussion-between-mishal2028-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap your LHS and RHS in the formula, "two.sided", and add commas:

```
t.test(
  `Average length of stay (days)`~`Peer group`,
  data = Clean,
  var.equal = TRUE,
  alternative = "two.sided"
)
```

However, this doesn't work on your sample data provided because there are no "Medium" sized hospitals, although it should work on the full data.

---

If we change two Large hospitals to Medium, we get this result:

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  Average length of stay (days) by Peer group
t = 0.83235, df = 8, p-value = 0.4294
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.460647  3.110647
sample estimates:
 mean in group Large hospitals mean in group Medium hospitals 
                         4.025                          3.200
```